# Sharing a dictionary (access only) across all processes of a multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function that I want to apply to a large number of items. The results are slotted into a dictionary when returned. The function involves referencing a number of two dictionaries that are never altered by the function, but need to be accessed by all processes within the pool.

My current code (below) works, but really blows up memory usage.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool

# Global dictionaries that I want read only access to: g1
# psm is an array, g1[key] maps to an array 
def find_match(m):
    dist = abs(g1[m] - psm)
    # Sort:
    dist = dist.sort_values()
    # Take nearest match
    rv[m] = dist.iloc[:1].index.values

manager = Manager()
rv = manager.dict()
pool = Pool(processes=4)   
res = pool.map_async(find_match, g1.keys()).get(99999)
```

My guess is that the dictionary and list that the function references (g1, psm) are being copied for each process -- how can I make them 'shared' between all processes? Perhaps importantly, I only need read-access to them, so not concerned about concurrency/locks.